# Click event on CSS element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add a click event to a css class so when clicked it switches to a different class. Specifically, I have a `character` class on `li` items that I would like to change to another class when the `li` item is clicked. Code:
html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    </head>
  
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Client Search</h1>
            <div id="searchWrapper">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="searchBar"
                    id="searchBar"
                    placeholder="search for a character"
                    onkeyup="myFunction()"
                />
            </div>
            <ul id="charactersList"></ul>
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #111d4a;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.container {
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
}

#charactersList {
    padding-inline-start: 0;
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

.character {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        'name image'
        'house image';
    text-align: left;
}
.character:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.character > h2 {
    grid-area: name;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.character > p {
    grid-area: house;
    margin: 0;
}

#searchBar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#searchWrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#searchWrapper::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

javaScript

```
const charactersList = document.getElementById('charactersList');
const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
let clientNames = [];

searchBar.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    const searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const filteredCharacters = clientNames.filter((character) => {
        return (
            character.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
            character.house.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
        );
    });
    displayCharacters(filteredCharacters);
});

const loadCharacters = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters');
        clientNames = await res.json();
        displayCharacters(hpCharacters);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const displayCharacters = (characters) => {
    const htmlString = characters
        .map((character) => {
            return `
            <li class="character">
                <h2>${character.name}</h2>
                <p>House: ${character.house}</p>
            </li>
        `;
        })
        .join('');
    charactersList.innerHTML = htmlString;
};

loadCharacters();


//change the display of characterListfrom none to grid
    function myFunction() {
      var charactersList = document.getElementById("charactersList");
      charactersList.style.display = "grid";

//also check if searchBar is empty and set display back to none
      var searchBar = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
      if (searchBar === ""){
        charactersList.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

Comment: I do not believe this code shows any `li` object with the class of `character`

Comment: Sorry, the list is generated dynamically in the javaScript code in the ``` displayCharacters() ``` function

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

I just made a CodePen to illustrate how to programmatically change CSS class names when a **li** item is clicked.  Check out this example and let me know if this clarifies the problem : )

#### JS

```
let list = document.getElementById('myList');
let items = ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'];

for(let item of items){
  let li = document.createElement("LI");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
  li.classList.add('blue');
  li.addEventListener("click", () => {
    li.classList.remove('blue');
    li.classList.add('red');
  });
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

#### HTML

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.blue{
  color: blue;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/CrowlsYung/pen/eYJRPjx

#### Suggested Change

```
<li class="character" onclick="handleItemClick(event)">
    <h2>${character.name}</h2>
    <p>House: ${character.house}</p>
</li>

function handleItemClick(e){
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('prevClass')
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('newClass');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is along the lines of what I'm looking for now I just need to figure out how to incorporate it into my code lol

Comment: The problem is I don't have an array in the js, it's called from an api.

Comment: I added a 'suggested change' section.  It's not exactly what you need, but should be close.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it using ``` character ``` and ``` newCharacter ``` instead of prevClass and newClass. I just changed the background color on ``` newCharacter ``` to test but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I should also point out my ultimate goal is actually to have the list item expand in size and have a textarea input inside of it.

Comment: Check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/CrowlsYung/pen/QWygzNb?editors=1111

I made an example of toggling classnames on a list item using onclick on an html li element!

Comment: I have exactly this code in my project now but it doesn't want to work in that context it doesn't seem https://codepen.io/MarcelPenn/pen/jOWwQbX?editors=0110

Comment: I think I have, I was missing the event argument in the handleItemClick(). Really appreciate the help!

Comment: I just edited your pen!  Try this: https://codepen.io/CrowlsYung/pen/QWygzOE?editors=0110

My bad, you need to pass an event parameter as well.  Also changed add / remove to toggle.

Comment: Yep, exactly!  No worries.  Glad to help out.

Comment: Thanks, can't really take credit as most of it is from a youtube tutorial lol